# Mapbox GL JS: Plotting markers with no coordinates

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

Does anyone know of a way of plotting markers in Mapbox GL JS that don't have coordinates?

I'm plotting a bunch of markers with popups on a map but I have a few markers that I don't want to plot in any precise location. Ideally, they would just sit in a box at the bottom of the screen and *not move* when you move the map.

I've made a container for them to sit in on HTML, now I just need to get them in it so they can sit relative to the webpage (rather than the map). Unless there's an easier work-around you can think of.

One idea I have is to replicate the marker from the map into an HTML object and then somehow reproduce the popup elements as they appear with the mapbox markers.

Here's the bit of JS:

```
// create a HTML element for each feature
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = "marker" + " " + typeTag + " " + impactTag;
    el.innerHTML = '<i class="' + symbol + '"></i>';

    // exclude Global markers for now
    if (feature.properties['location'] !== 'Global') {

    // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
    .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 10, closeButton: false }) // add popups
    .setHTML('<h4 style="padding-bottom: 4px; border-bottom: 2px solid ' + colors[impactTag] + ';">' + feature.properties['title'] + '</h4><ul class="list-group list-tooltip"><li>Area of study: ' + feature.properties['location'] + '</li><li><div style="display:inline-block" class=' + impactTag + '>' + popupIcon[type] + "</div>"  
    + impactTag + " " + 'that.</li></ul><p class="summary">' 
    + summary + '</p><p class="citation"><a href="'
    + url + '" target="_blank">' + clipCitation + "),</a><span class='citation2'> " + feature.properties['journal'] + '</span></p>'))
    .addTo(map);
    }

    // plot Global markers within globalcontainer - this is where I'm stumped...
    else {
    
    }
```

Comment: Just to clarify - you want a marker pin to remain on a line along the very bottom on the map viewport in a way that the marker *does not move* when you move the map? I don't think the [marker API](You may be able to hack something together to automatically calculate the coordinates) allows that - you may be able to hack something together to automatically calculate the screen coordinates again when the map moves, but that sounds like a Bad Idea. Can you tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish? Maybe there's a better solution not using markers.

Comment: Thanks Rafael. I've edited the question, but it's just like you say: I want the markers to *not move* when I move the map. My gut instinct is the best way to do it is to make html objects that look like the markers and show pop-ups like the markers but aren't related in any way to the mapbox map.

Answer (score 0):

You just want an HTML overlay, not a marker. The easiest way is something like this:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="overlay" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;">Overlay content here.</div>
```